# Проверка на одинаковое значение RedBeanPhp

Tags: php, mysql, telegram-bot, redbeanphp

мне нужна помощь. Как сделать проверку на одинаковое значение в таблице mysql? К примеру, у меня есть переменная $chat_id, которая всегда меняет свое значение и когда пользовать вводит определенную команду, то чат ид попадает в базу, и мне нужно, чтобы повторное значение чат ид не записывалось. Другими словами сделать проверку на одинаковый Чат-Ид. Я вот начал делать, но это почему-то не работает, можете помочь исправить?

```
$book = R::findOne('newchat', 'chat_id = ?', array([$chat_id]));
        if ( $book ) {
            //чат-ид существует
            if ($chat_id = $user->chat_id) {
                //если чат-ид совпадает, то нужно выдать сообщение
                $suc = 'Успешно';
            } else {
                $error = 'Ошибка';
            }
        }
```

```
newchat - таблица
chat_id - поле в таблице newchat
```

```
$chat_id = $result['message']['chat']['id'];
```

Использую библиотеку RedBeanPhp, буду очень благодарен, если сможете помочь

Comment: *мне нужно, чтобы повторное значение чат ид не записывалось* Это делают путём создания уникального индекса по нужному полю или выражению. А в приложении просто отлавливают (или игнорируют) ошибку дублирования ключа.

Comment: Я уже так сделал, а как отлавливать ошибку дублирования ключа? Хочу просто текст другой выводить, если такой чат и уже есть